# Add additional condition to MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I need some help with a MySql Query.  My existing query returns all rows which have 100001 as the query_id, sorted by priceperadult ASC.

However, I want it to only return the best rate per hotel, so need to add to the statement so only one rate per hotel shows, whats the best way to achieve this?

```
SELECT * FROM `search_results` WHERE `query_id` = '100001' ORDER BY `priceperadult` ASC
```

**Sample Data**

*query_id, priceperadult, hotel_name*

100001, 100, Hotel 1

100001, 200, Hotel 1

100001, 100, Hotel 2

100001, 200, Hotel 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking to use `min()`:

```
SELECT query_id, MIN(priceperadult), hotel_name
FROM search_results 
WHERE query_id = '100001' 
GROUP BY query_id, hotel_name
```

Comment: Thats great thanks for answer. But how do i then sort the list by MIN(priceperadult) in ASC fashion? i.e. lowest rate of all hotels first?